# java.lang.nullPointerException while running testcase

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

package automate;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FunctionalTest {

```
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest

public void browserConfiguration() {

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C://Users//Admin//workspace//Guru99Test//drivers//geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://letskodeit.teachable.com/p/practice");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.manage().window().maximize();

}

@Test

public void checkRadioOptions() {

/*List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio']"));*/
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.name("cars"));


boolean flag = false;

flag = element.get(1).isSelected();

if (flag==true) {

    System.out.println("Do Nothing");
}
    else {

        element.get(2).click();
        }
}
```

}

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at automate.FunctionalTest.checkRadioOptions(FunctionalTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Just check I have added the script code as well.

Comment: At which line exactly is the code crashing? Can't see rule numbers here.

Comment: Got the cause.Thanks FDM.  next time will post along with rule numbers

Answer (score 2):

`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

The driver was already created in the starting. This line was causing the error as it was assigning the driver to a new variable.

It should have been `driver = new Firefox Driver();`